# Caching Canvas Through Pages

Tags: javascript, caching, canvas

What I have, is a canvas which renders a still image. Once. However whenever the user refreshes, it has to render again. Is there a way to have the user render it once, then store it in the cache and use it again later? Or is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already figured it out. Using canvas.toDataURL provides a base64 encoded string, which I can then use later to resupply the image. Example code:

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
     if(typeof localStorage.canvasCache != "undefined") {
         // create the image tag
     } else {
         // render canvas
         localStorage.canvasCache = canvas.toDataURL();
     }
}
```